# MySQL Correlated sub queries

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can any one help me i have problem with Correlated nested sub queries 
i.e., when i am trying to use  grand parent column in nested sub query then i got this error

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'scu.iUserId' in 'where clause'

### Query:

```
    SELECT 
      scu.iUserId,
      (SELECT 
        SUM(
          sbs.`iNoPointsBeginning` + 
          (SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(BehaviorPts), 0) AS StudentPts 
          FROM
            (SELECT 
              (
                COUNT(sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId) * sbi.iPointValue
              ) AS BehaviorPts 
            FROM
              scn_behavior_incident_submission sbis 
              JOIN scn_behavior_incident_actors sbia 
                ON sbia.iIncidentSubmissionId = sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId 
              LEFT JOIN scn_behavior_incidents sbi 
                ON sbi.iIncidentId = sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId 
            WHERE sbia.iUserId = scu.iUserId
              AND sbia.eActorType  'Witness' 
              AND sbis.iSchoolId = '875' 
            GROUP BY sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId) AS BehaviorTotal)
        ) AS stu_pt 
      FROM
        scn_behavior_settings sbs 
      WHERE sbs.`iSchoolId` = '875') 

    FROM
      scn_sections_members AS scm 
      INNER JOIN scn_users AS scu 
        ON scu.iUserId = scm.iStudentId
```

Comment: Is this still a pending item for you (in addition to the other you posted that were very similar)?

Answer (score 2):

The two levels of nesting cause this error. The very internal subquery does not "know" `scu` which is defined in the external query.

Try to rewrite it without inline subqueries. Not sure if this is the proper way but you'll get the idea. (the `sbs` table seems unrelated to the other ones so I made that a `CROSS JOIN`. Edit appropriately if there is a relationship):

```
SELECT 
    scu.iUserId,
    sbs.iNoPointsBeginning 
    + COUNT(sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId) * COALESCE(sbi.iPointValue, 0)
      AS stu_pt 
FROM
    ( SELECT 
          SUM(sbs.iNoPointsBeginning) AS iNoPointsBeginning
      FROM 
          scn_behavior_settings sbs 
      WHERE sbs.iSchoolId = '97'
    ) AS sbs 
  CROSS JOIN
      scn_sections_members AS scm 
  INNER JOIN scn_users AS scu 
    ON scu.iUserId = scm.iStudentId 
  LEFT JOIN
          scn_behavior_incident_submission sbis 
        JOIN scn_behavior_incident_actors sbia 
          ON  sbia.iIncidentSubmissionId = sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId 
          AND sbia.eActorType = 'Witness' 
          AND sbis.iSchoolId = '97' 
        LEFT JOIN scn_behavior_incidents sbi 
          ON sbi.iIncidentId = sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId 
    ON sbia.iUserId = scu.iUserId
GROUP BY scu.iUserId
       , sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you (temporarily) remove that messy tangle of sub-queries, you'll see that you are saying:

```
SELECT scu.iUserId 
FROM scn_sections_members AS scm 
INNER JOIN scn_users AS scu 
ON scu.iUserId = scm.iStudentId
```

For MySQL to tell you that the column is unknown, it must mean that the column doesn't exist. What is the definition of scn_users? Put a iUserId column in that table and then at least that part of your problem will be over.