# Correlated sub queries in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can any one help me i have problem with Correlated nested sub queries i.e., when i am trying to use grand parent column in nested sub query then i got this error

Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'scu.iUserId' in 'where clause'

Query:

```
SELECT 
  scu.iUserId,
  (SELECT 
    SUM(
      sbs.`iNoPointsBeginning` + 
      (SELECT 
        COALESCE(SUM(BehaviorPts), 0) AS StudentPts 
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          (
            COUNT(sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId) * sbi.iPointValue
          ) AS BehaviorPts 
        FROM
          scn_behavior_incident_submission sbis 
          JOIN scn_behavior_incident_actors sbia 
            ON sbia.iIncidentSubmissionId = sbis.iIncidentSubmissionId 
          LEFT JOIN scn_behavior_incidents sbi 
            ON sbi.iIncidentId = sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId 
        WHERE sbia.iUserId = scu.iUserId
          AND sbia.eActorType  'Witness' 
          AND sbis.iSchoolId = '97' 
        GROUP BY sbis.iBehaviorIncidentId) AS BehaviorTotal)
    ) AS stu_pt 
  FROM
    scn_behavior_settings sbs 
  WHERE sbs.`iSchoolId` = '97') 
FROM
  scn_sections_members AS scm 
  INNER JOIN scn_users AS scu 
    ON scu.iUserId = scm.iStudentId
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that specific error message, but there _has_ to be a better way to write that query.  (+1 for nicely indented code, though.)

Comment: ...also, it looks like you're probably missing some join conditions on the `sbs` table. It would help if you could describe in plain English what you're actually trying to calculate with this query.

Comment: The two levels of nesting cause this error. The very inner subquery does not "know" `scu` which is defined in the external query.

Comment: It seems to be a perfect candidate for using with htsql: http://htsql.org/doc/overview.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Correlated sub queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905074/mysql-correlated-sub-queries)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Correlated sub queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905074/mysql-correlated-sub-queries)